# Left Join not giving desired result

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two Datasets

```
FEES                    PAYMENTS            
CrsCode InstNo  FEE     Regno   CRSCODE Instno  Payment
CA1        -2   100     R1     CA1      -2       100
CA1        -1   200     R1     CA1      -1       200
CA1         1   200     R1     CA1       1       200
CA1         2   300                 

DESIRED OUTPUT                          
REGNO   CRSCODE INSTNO  FEE PAID    DIFF        
R1          CA1  -2   100   100     0       
R1          CA1  -1   200   200     0       
R1          CA1   1   200   200     0       
R1          CA1   2   300   0       300     

OUTPUT I AM GETTING                         
REGNO   CRSCODE INSTNO     FEE     PAID  DIFF       
R1          CA1   -2       100     100   0
R1          CA1   -1       200     200   0      
R1          CA1    1       200     200   0      
null        null   null    300     null  null
```

Query i am using

```
select a.Regno,a.crscode,b.fee,a.payment,b.fee-a.payment from Fees as b Left join
Payments as a on a.CrsCode=b.CrsCode and a.InstNo=b.InstNo
```

Please find [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56ac1/7)

Comment: A `Fees LEFT JOIN Payments` would show the extra row you want and some of the columns correctly. But why should the `CA1         2   300` row be associated with `R1` ?

Comment: that row, is the Fees not recieved

Comment: OK, but why `R1`? And not `R7`? Or `R167`?

Comment: R1 is regno means same person, He has 4,5 Inst to be paid, Need to find how many paid, how many Left and if any balance from already paid

Comment: Why minus voted

Comment: @AmritpalSingh I would guess at least partly because of all the teeth-pulling we've had to do to get more information from you. There are a *lot* of comments below asking for clarification of various things, which don't happen with a well-thought-out, complete question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH regCrs AS 
(
  SELECT regno, crsCode FROM dbo.PAYMENTS
  GROUP BY regno, crsCode
),
f AS 
( 
  SELECT f.crsCode, f.instNo, f.fee, regCrs.regno
  FROM regCrs INNER JOIN dbo.FEES AS f
  ON regCrs.crsCode = f.crsCode
)
SELECT f.regno, f.crsCode, f.instNo, f.fee,
  paid = COALESCE(p.payment, 0),
  DIFF = f.fee - COALESCE(p.payment, 0)
FROM f
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PAYMENTS AS p
ON f.crsCode = p.crsCode
AND f.instNo = p.instNo;
```

Results:

```
REGNO  CRSCODE  INSTNO  FEE  PAID  DIFF
=====  =======  ======  ===  ====  ====
r1     CA1      -2      100  100   0
r1     CA1      -1      200  200   0
r1     CA1      1       200  200   0
r1     CA1      2       300  0     300
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56ac1/18)

Comment: Your solution is working i need to test on my real dataset, As there are millions of rows.

Comment: Well this probably won't perform fantastically against millions of rows, but you haven't really given us enough information to properly solve any performance issues that might arise. If you want to "dumb down" the "complex queries" so we can't help optimize the *source* of this data, then there's not much we can do to help optimize the end result.

Comment: rightly said, i wil come up with all tables.For a quick solution i posted the above question

Comment: @AmritpalSingh at this point it may work better to pick an answer here since it sounds like this works for the question **as written** and open a new question about a scalable solution.

Answer (score 4):

- First, you need to reverse the outer join (either from left join to right join or by reverting the order): `FROM Fees LEFT JOIN Payments`
- Then you'll need the `COALESCE()` function to convert the `NULL` produced by the outer join to zeros, for the `payment` column.
- And last, you have to find out how the column `RegNo` should be populated when it will be `NULL`. I suppose the `CrsCode` means a Person or Account identification code. Do you have a table for Persons or Accounts, with `CrsCode` as primary key and a `RegNo` column? If yes, here is a solution:

  ```
  SELECT 
      a.Regno, 
      f.crscode, 
      f.InstNo,
      f.fee,
      COALESCE(p.payment, 0) AS paid,
      f.fee - COALESCE(p.payment, 0) AS diff
  FROM 
      Fees AS f 
    JOIN AccountTable AS a
      ON  f.CrsCode = a.CrsCode
    LEFT JOIN Payments AS p
      ON  f.CrsCode = p.CrsCode 
      AND f.InstNo = p.InstNo ;
  ```

Comment: It returns repeated values, Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56ac1/13

Comment: I ask again: Do you have an Account table? Or a Persons table?

Comment: Please check the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56ac1/14 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56ac1/15 with distinct clause

Comment: Please answer the question.

Comment: Yes apart from above mentioned table i have Student Table which contact unique regno

Comment: @AmritpalSingh well if that table helps to define the relationships or the query results - especially the relationship between CrsCode and RegNo - you should include that information in the question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i am generating my result on these two dataset, they are not as is in a table form, I am obtaining them through two different complex queries which i am hereby joining, I will not be referring any other table for result.The Registration table contain Regno,name,address etc details

Comment: If you don't have a table with both `(CrsCode, RegNo)` columns in it, another question: In the `Payments` dataset, do all rows with same `CrsCode` have the same `RegNo`?

Comment: @ypercube that was the assumption I made (no idea if it was right since we were only shown three rows with all the same values).

Comment: I was going to add: "if yes, then Aaron's solution will work fine."

Comment: Please give me little i will come up with all tables, while i am testing @AaronBertrand solution

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want:

```
select a.Regno,a.crscode,b.fee,a.payment,b.fee-a.payment 
from  Fees
Left join Payments
 on Payments.CrsCode=Fees.CrsCode and Payments.InstNo=Fees.InstNo
```

Comment: Problem is that the `RegNo` is null for one row, which the OP does not want -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8c2f/17

Comment: @bluefeet yes, I don't Want null, May be swapped my tables in my query thats why i was minus voted

Comment: Your problem is the data doesn't support the result set you want. You have no payments for fee 300.

Comment: @HLGEM I need to find out of 4,5 installment how many paid and how much paid